# Kubernetes terminating state VS ongoing TCP connections

Tags: docker, kubernetes, tcp, load-balancing, endpoint

I have a question concerning some of the transitions of the [k8s pod lifecycle](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-termination). I want to know whether it is possible to preserve an ongoing TCP connection after the `preStop` hook begins to run. The motivation/test is

1. kubectl port-forward mypod-abc 12:34
2. curl -v http://localhost:12/myserver/longOperation (runs for 30 seconds)
3. kubectl delete pod mypod-abc
4. 30 seconds later, get the response back from the pod

I found a post [*Kubernetes pods graceful shutdown with TCP connections (Spring boot)*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60276403/kubernetes-pods-graceful-shutdown-with-tcp-connections-spring-boot#:%7E:text=Any%20existing%20TCP%20connections%20to,%2C%20server%20or%20network%20stack) which states

> When a pod is deleted in k8s, the Pod Endpoint removal from Services is triggered at the same time as the SIGTERM signal to the container(s).
>
> At this point the cluster nodes will be reconfigured to remove any rules directing new traffic to the Pod. Any existing TCP connections to the Pod/containers will remain in connection tracking until they are closed (by the client, server or network stack).

This is exactly what I want to happen! However, this post is two years old and when I test locally...

```
bash-3.2$ curl -v http://localhost:12/myserver/longOperation -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Keep-Alive: timeout=20, max=100"
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:12...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 12 (#0)
> GET /myserver/longOperation HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:12
> User-Agent: curl/7.79.1
> Accept: */*
> Connection: keep-alive
> Keep-Alive: timeout=20, max=100
> 
* Empty reply from server
* Closing connection 0
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

I find that after deleting my pod (which has a `preStop` hook that sleeps for 5 minutes, and a `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` of 300), I immediately get an empty response! Is there any way to configure Kubernetes so terminating pods keep their ongoing TCP connections?

Comment: If kubernetes is stopping pods by sending `SIGTERM`, you can write code that catches `SIGTERM` and does something other than exiting.

Comment: Hi @larsks! thanks for the idea, but the `preStop` hook already achieves that :) My issue seems to be with the [pod lifecycle](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-termination) where "At the same time as the kubelet is starting graceful shutdown, the control plane removes that shutting-down Pod from Endpoints".

Answer (score 0):

Once you initiate termination of a Pod, e.g. with a `kubectl delete <po>`, the Pod Status is set immediately to "Terminating". Also, the Pod IP is cleared immediately from the Endpoint resource that was pointing to it. Simultaneously, its `preStop` hook is executed. After the completion of the `preStop` hook the Pod will be issued with a TERM signal, which is a soft attempt to stop it giving it room to do so in its own time. Also, the Termination Grace Period will [start ticking](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/#container-hooks). If the Pod is still not terminated after the Termination Grace Period has expired, the Pod will be issued a KILL signal that will stop it for sure. The official documentation regarding the topic can be found [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-termination).

From a network connectivity point of view this means:

- After Pod termination initiation, K8s will reconfigure its routing to no longer open new connections with the terminating Pod. However, this involves a cascade of several processes, e.g. reconfiguring the Endpoint resource, rewriting the iptables rules on the worker nodes, so that this won't take affect instantaneously.
- Open connections will remain open with packets being sent directly to the IP address of the terminating Pod! An open connection will remain open until either the client closes it, the Pod closes it or the Pod (meaning the underlying container) stopped and removed.

For the problem at hand, I would say that the observed behavior is not in line with K8s standard behavior and might be a specific problem of the K8s provider you are using. On a side note, the `preStop` hook should be replaced with proper handling of the TERM signal by your application, i.e. keep running until in-flight connections have been closed.

Comment: Thanks so much Fritz! I agree, the observed behavior looks different than what I'd like to see happening. I'll get more hands on with our configuration, just wanted to confirm it was even possible to maintain open connections.

I acknowledge the lack of a proper signal handler is not ideal. I'm unfortunately stretched a little thin and probably won't be able to implement that. But thank you for the clarification "Also, the Termination Grace Period will start ticking." I thought the grace period was the max duration of the preStop hook!

Comment: The termination grace period runs parallel to the preStop hook and ensures that the Pod is definitely terminated after a defined period, so the preStop hook will get terminated if is exceeds the duration of the termination grace period (interestingly it will get granted 2 extra seconds before termination). Nevertheless, the termination grace period will also terminate Pods if no preStop hook is defined in case applications don't shut down after a mere TERM signal.